# structure name with number in C

Tags: c, structure

I'm new to C and I'm trying to create a structure to manage books:

```
typedef struct bookManagement{
    char *name;
    char *author;
    char *country;
    char *genre;
    int year;
} book;
```

How can I create structure name with a number, for example:

```
main(){
book 1={"The great Gatsby","F. Scott Fitzgerald","USA","novel",1925};
}
```

My IDE reported an error for this statement:

> "[Error] expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant"

Comment: You can use a digit in an identifier (name), but not as the first character... `a1` is fine, `1` is not.  But why do you need numbers as names anyway?  Do you need an array of structures, possibly?

Comment: First character should be an alphabet or an underscore. You should see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f8y25b.aspx#Anchor_0).

Comment: You should really find a good, simple C tutorial and learn the basic syntax.  Knowing that an identifier cannot being with a digit is something you should learn within the first 10 minutes of studying the C language, certainly long before you tackle data types like structures.

Comment: You can also  instead use `book 1` as `book_1` this is because c variable cannot have spaces in between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie, page 35:

> There are some restrictions on the names of variables and symbolic constants. Names are made up of letters and digits; the first character must be a letter.

So what you want is something like this:

```
typedef struct bookManagement{
    char *name;
    char *author;
    char *country;
    char *genre;
    int year;
} book;

int main(){
    book book1={"The great Gatsby","F. Scott Fitzgerald","USA","novel",1925};
}
```

If you want to do some sort of indexing with the numbers, I think you'll want to use a struct array. If you need more info on that, I recommend you read [this guide](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-initializing-array-of-structure/) as it gives a few different options for the ways that can be done. Good luck learning!